# How to determine if a string is a valid IPv6 address in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp, ip-address, ipv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPv6 parsing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962664/ipv6-parsing-in-c)

I need to check strings if they are valid IPv6 addresses in C++.

There are elegant solutions for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799060/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-ipv4-or-ipv6-address-in-c) and rather ugly regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses).

Is there a good way to do this in C++ ?

I'm currently using this, but it doesn't work on Windows XP (inet_pton() is missing):

```
unsigned char buf[sizeof(struct in6_addr)];
bool isvalid= inet_pton(PF_INET6, (const char *)addr, buf);
```

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` (from duplicate question) looks to be available in XP if you don't have `inet_pton()`

Comment: Vote to reopen, since the linked question explicitly tags C, while this question tags C++. The linked C question may lack some answers, which requires C++ libraries, like boost. Actually, there is at least one [option](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1gT45B8BaN64dnSr), which uses boost::asio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Linux, or in Windows since Windows 2000. (See the section of that document page entitled "Example code using AI_NUMERICHOST")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WSAStringToAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), available since Windows 2000.